# Contract flipper build fails

Tags: ink

I'm following instructions in substrate document. I build contract flipper and get this error:
[image]

How can I fix this error? Thanks

Comment: have you used latest nightly rust? Have a look [this link](https://matrix.to/#/!utTuYglskDvqRRMQta:matrix.org/$Mk4XDWUA6-dFgnT1EPcInejMsVjoV-U7MJp__6XTIoY?via=matrix.org&via=t2bot.io&via=cardinal.ems.host) you may find solution.

Comment: I use `cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 test` rather `cargo +nightly test` to test and `cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 contract build` to build rather `cargo +nightly contract build` today and it works for me. My `cargo contract version cargo-contract 1.5.0-unknown-x86_64-apple-darwin` and `rustc 1.66.0-nightly (c0983a9aa 2022-10-12))`