# Ink! playground contract flipper not building due to errors

Tags: ink, error

i know that this is a duplicate, but problem must be resolved...

So, there are 2 "solutions":

1. [Contract flipper build fails](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4810/contract-flipper-build-fails)
2. [error[E0158] when testing default contract from flipper](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4785/errore0158-when-testing-default-contract-from-flipper)

But not a single one worked for me. I still get error that :
"associated consts cannot be referenced in patter" rustc(E0158).

Is there anything else that could be done to resolve this?

Versions:

1. cargo contract: cargo-contract 1.5.0-unknown-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
2. rustc: rustc 1.66.0-nightly (470e518c4 2022-09-27)

Comment: have you used latest nightly rust? Have a look [this link](https://matrix.to/#/!utTuYglskDvqRRMQta:matrix.org/$Mk4XDWUA6-dFgnT1EPcInejMsVjoV-U7MJp__6XTIoY?via=matrix.org&via=t2bot.io&via=cardinal.ems.host) you may find solution.

Comment: "associated consts cannot be referenced in pattern" This is a known issue see https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1418. We will try and get a release out soon with this fix

Comment: Okay then, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use `cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 test` rather `cargo +nightly test` to test and `cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 contract build` to build rather `cargo +nightly contract build` today and it works for me. My `cargo contract version cargo-contract 1.5.0-unknown-x86_64-apple-darwin` and `rustc 1.66.0-nightly (c0983a9aa 2022-10-12))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following configuration

```
cargo-contract v2.0.0-alpha.4 (https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract#6626f56f):
cargo-contract
cargo 1.64.0 (387270bc7 2022-09-16)
```

and use ink! version 4  https://crates.io/crates/ink/4.0.0-alpha.3